# using stacks to check for matching brackets in java

Tags: java, brackets, stack

hi guys I am trying to create a program to allow a user to input a sequence of brackets (one at a time) and check to see whether there is a corresponding ending bracket. The brackets are entered on a new line every time to aid in the reading. I've set up an ADT for it but just cant think of how to get the while loop going and the checking...... I know if an ( bracket is entered i should push that into the stack and when a ( is entered i should pop one of the stack but I just cant work out the bits in the middle any help would be loved :)

```
//main code   
import java.util.*;

public class SameBrackets
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Stack bracket = new Stack();
      Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.print("Enter bracket > ");
      String bracketentered = kybd.next();


          if ("(".equals(bracketentered) )
          {
                 bracket.push(bracketentered);
                 System.out.println(") needed");
          }
          else if (")".equals(bracketentered))
          {
              bracket.pop();
              System.out.println("( needed");
          }


      }
  }
```

//ADT code

```
public class Stack
{
    private String[] a;         //String array
    private int top;

    public Stack()
    {
       a = new String[1];           //create String array
       top = 0;                      
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
         return top == 0;
    }

    public String pop()          //pop String element
    {
        top--;
        return(a[top]);         //underflow not protected
    }

    public void push(String x)      //push String element
    {
        if (top == a.length)
        {
            resize();
        }
        a[top] = x;
        top++;
    }  

    private void resize()
    {
        String[] temp = new String[a.length * 2];   //resize String array
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        {
            temp[i] = a[i];
         }
        a = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really need stack? May be create counter, instead of stack. When you push bracket, then do i++, when you pop bracket - do i--. Check on pop if i < 0 then entered string is corrupted.

Comment: Using a stack is beneficial when you would like to evaluate expressions too for example in reverse polish notation. That is the reason why checking parentheses is done this way historically - otherwise you only need a simple counter for the task.

Answer (score 1):

- why do you need a stack? you can just have a counter, increment it on '(' and decrement it on ')' - every time you decrement it make sure its value is still non-negative.
- not sure what is your question about the loop. you can have a while loop that is terminated by specific input (for example - 'q').

---

As for your loop question:

```
input = getInput(scanner);
while(input != null) {
  // do what you want with the input

  input = getInput(scanner);
}

private static String getInput(Scanner scanner) {
  get the input from the scanner here - return null if no more input.
}
```

Comment: ive been told to use the stack which is what has thrown me but i set it up so the stack is using an array that i can add to..... i know the method in enlish is wrting the code.... need to add open brackets to the stack and then when a closing bracket enetered it gets rid of the opening one as it has been used so if anything left at the end of the sequence an eneding one has been missed if u get me

Comment: A stack is useful if he later decides to support different kinds of brackets, e.g. '(' and '['.

Comment: well thats where  the program will be heading

Comment: @Jonny_Appleby12 - so what is your question?

Comment: my question is how do i write the code as i know the method im just haveing a brian freeze and cant think how to write it :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like:

```
if ("(".equals(bracketentered) ) {
    bracket.push(bracketentered);
} else if (")".equals(bracketentered)) {
    bracket.pop();
}
if ( bracket.isEmpty () ) {
    System.out.println("( needed");
} else {
    System.out.println(") needed");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to implement your own stack, a `LinkedList` (specifically the [`Deque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) interface it implements) can do that already. But it's a good exercise.

Your code is missing two thing.

- a loop that continues until some end is reached. The end of `System.in` is unfortunately not that easy to reach when you enter text from the console. It's usually Ctrl-D that can end. Adding your own stop mechanism is a good idea, most people don't know how to end the program otherwise.
- you need to check that the bracket popped off the stack matches the bracket just entered.
- you should check that the stack is actually empty at the end.

If you do that you end up with something like

```
// a stack. You can use your own instead.
Deque<String> stack = new LinkedList<String>();
Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);

String bracketentered;

// 1) repeat while there is more, CTRL-D should end here.
while (kybd.hasNext()) {
    System.out.print("Enter bracket or 'q' to quit:");
    bracketentered = kybd.next();

    if (bracketentered.equals("q")) {
        break; // end this loop
    }

    if ("(".equals(bracketentered)) {
        // just push to stack
        stack.push(bracketentered);
    }
    else if (")".equals(bracketentered)) {
        // in case the stack is empty:
        // stack.pop() throws an exception
        // stack.poll() returns null
        String opposingBracket = stack.poll();

        // there must be a "(" on the stack(
        if (!"(".equals(opposingBracket)) {
            System.out.println("Wrong bracket");
        }
    }
    else {
        // in case it's not ( or )
        System.out.println("Illegal input:" + bracketentered);
    }
}
// 3) loop finished via "q" or end of input - check that stack is empty
if (!stack.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("You forgot to close the following brackets:");
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.print(stack.poll() + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

---

Regarding stack vs counting brackets in a loop: A very simple bracket counting algorithm that checks only at the end would allow `) (`, a smarter one that checks during each step may fail for multi bracket combinations like `[ ( ] )`. A stack makes sure they are correctly hierarchical, e.g. `[ () ]`.

Comment: what is the poll function u are usin

Comment: @Jonny_Appleby12 I've used the one from [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#poll%28%29) - essentially your `pop` method but with underflow protection

Comment: right cause i cant use a linklist right now in this program even though i know where ur coming from :(

Comment: @Jonny_Appleby12 you don't have to, just replace the `LinkedList` with your `Stack` and then use `pop` instead of `poll`.

Comment: Ive done that but now if the user puts a ) as the first input it fails how would you fix that ??

Comment: and if you put ) without a matching ( it fails